# How do I change a device name from the iCloud web site?

Tags: iphone, icloud, find-my-iphone

My family has several iPhones listed under the "Find my iPhone" section of the iCloud web site. Unfortunately, they all have the same name "'s iPhone".

Two of the phones are older models and have been given to other family members. One of them I have been able to change the name directly on the device. The other I cannot change the name directly on the device because the device currently won't power up.

One day I hope to fix this, so I don't want to remove the device from the account.  But at the same time, it's annoying having two devices with the same name. The other device is correctly named, so I don't want to change its name, I want to change the name of the (currently) inoperative device.

How can I do this directly from the iCloud web site?

Comment: Unfortunately, no way to do so. It's one way communication - from device to iCloud and not vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

You change the name on each device in: Settings > General > About > Name.

The web site only reports what the device calls itself and does not offer a push rename feature or relabel feature.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 don’t shoot the messenger. This is the way and the answer

Comment: Not all devices have a rename option. So the question stands.
For example, XBOX name does not change a device name when using Apple TV+ app. It is marked as Microsoft and this breaks the whole list visually